# Scalable setup for styling polymer elements

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

It seems that for styling polymer 1.0 elements there are basically two options:

1. styling via the **custom-style**:

Styling can be applied to a `<style is="custom-style">...</style>` section. In this, you can adjust predefined styling.

2. Styling via the **dom-module** element:

Another example is that you can style this element by adjusting the element in the file of the element itsel adjusting the `<dom-module id="xx"><template>...</template></dom-module>`.

The second method allows for more rigorous changes. However, the second method will require editing the polymer HTML file itself. If you'd run Polymer via bower includes this would mean every time there's an update to the markup file, all the changes would be overwritten.

Does someone else perhaps have experience with working on styling Polymer, and is there another way to make rigorous changes without adjusting a Polymer source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer supports [CSS mixins](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-css-mixins) and [CSS variables](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-css-properties) that would allow an element author to expose styling points that a user could customize without modifying the original source.

The following example element defines default styles and then applies a given CSS mixin (`--x-foo-body`) if available:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <style>
      .body {
        padding: 1em;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        @apply --x-foo-body;
      }
    </style>
    <p class="body">Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </template>
  ...
```

The user of this element could change the element's styles for `.body` by using a `custom-style` (*Note: No need for `is="custom-style"` inside `dom-module`*):

```
// index.html
<style is="custom-style">
  x-foo.my-styles {
    --x-foo-body: {
      padding: 0;
      color: red;
    };
  }
</style>

<x-foo class="my-styles"></x-foo>
```

The same idea is followed with CSS variables. This example element uses a default `font-color` of `blue` for its heading text but allows it to be overridden by a CSS variable named `--x-foo-heading-color`.

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <style>
      .heading {
        color: var(--x-foo-heading-color, blue);
      }
    </style>
    <h2 class=".heading">Hello world</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </template>
  ...
```

And the user could change the element's heading color with a `custom-style` (*Note: No need for `is="custom-style"` inside `dom-module`*):

```
// index.html
<style is="custom-style">
  x-foo.my-heading-style {
    --x-foo-heading-color: green;
  }
</style>

<x-foo class="my-heading-style"></x-foo>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        .heading {
          font-family: sans-serif;
          color: var(--x-foo-heading-color, gray);
        }
        .body {
          padding: 1em;
          font-size: 0.9em;
          @apply --x-foo-body;
        }
      </style>
      <h2 class="heading">[[heading]]</h2>
      <p class="body">Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({ is: 'x-foo' });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

</head>
<body>
  <style is="custom-style">
    .x-heading {
      --x-foo-heading-color: green;
    }
    .x-body {
      --x-foo-body: {
        padding: 0.5em;
        font-family: Courier New;
        background-color: lightgray;
      };
    }
  </style>

  <x-foo heading="Default style"></x-foo>
  <x-foo heading="Custom heading color" class="x-heading"></x-foo>
  <x-foo heading="Custom heading color and body styles" class="x-heading x-body"></x-foo>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/WoxZpE?editors=1000)

You could read more about theming elements in [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/first-element/step-5).

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation. So if you'd want to rigorously change a element, you'd typically want to create more end points. For existing elements you'd then have diverge from the standard Polymer element and create a new one with the additional end point, in other words customized element that's not in the standard bower package?